# Use setonItemChange Listner in viewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I used the `ViewPager`, and want to get the next item, and the previous item when scrolling the page to left and to right. I used `viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener` like [this example](http://code.google.com/p/electricsleep/source/browse/trunk/src/com/androsz/electricsleepbeta/app/HistoryMonthActivity.java#36) but when scrolling it still gives me the same content.

This is my code:

```
    @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            mFocusedPage = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            if (state ==ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                if (mFocusedPage == 0) {
                    clientMeterString="firstitem:number1";
                } else if (mFocusedPage == 2) {
                    clientMeterString="seconditem:number2";
                }

                awesomePager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you are trying to achieve, but I think that calling `setCurrentItem` always with the value 1 is the thing that makes you see the same content.

For getting the previous page (the one that is being hidden) you should use the `SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING`, like:

```
   awesomePager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
        private int prevPage = -1;
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // after page is selected do something with your prevPage 
            // eg: compare to "position" to check if it's from the left or right
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            if (arg0 == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                prevPage = awesomePager.getCurrentItem();
            }
        }
    });
```